# Accessing a website over L2TP using OrangePi as a middle man?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, routing, android, l2tp

Android 13 no longer supports L2TP. I need to access my work website over L2TP. The only solution I could came up with so far is to use a single board computer as the middle man to handle L2TP traffic and pass it to my phone. But I don't have a technical solution. My SBC is an OrangePi PC with Ubuntu Linux on board so it supports L2TP. I can connect the Pi to my phone's hotspot over Wi-Fi. I can ssh to the Pi from my phone. But how to set up the Pi as a server or maybe do some routing/forwarding to access my work website from my phone's browser?

Comment: If you already have Pi running why not use it as Wireguard endpoint. Then you could simply use the existing Wireguard Android app for connecting to the pi.

Comment: Tell your work's IT people that L2TP has been proven insecure and deprecated by Microsoft (its creator) for more than a decade. Ask them to provide you with a modern VPN protocol/server to connect to.

Comment: Cross-posted from Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1467001/331791